# Why Go provides an incorrect ENV on Mac ( os package ) Go

Tags: macos, go

```
echo $GOPATH
/Users/me/go/
```

In go the code below outputs `/Users/me/go:`  . Notice `:`

```
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"


func main(){
p := os.Getenv("GOPATH")
fmt.Println(p)
}
```

However I've tested it on linux and the dots (`:`) are replaced by a slash ( which I think is the correct form so we have `/Users/me/go/`. I'm wondering why is this inconsistency and if it's actually a bug.

System Info:

```
go version
go version go1.3 darwin/amd64

OS: OSX 10.7.5
```

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: I don't see this myself with Go 1.3 on OS X10.9.3.

Comment: I'm not positive, but that may be either your shell or the OS messing with the variable before the command is run.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like os.Getenv just stubs out to the syscall: http://darwin.golang.org/src/pkg/os/env.go?s=2363:2393#L69

Comment: Plus, the syscall code itself (http://darwin.golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/env_unix.go) is the same on Linux and Darwin (note the "_unix" suffix).

Comment: The colon (:) is probably a path separator. Is it possible that you're appending an empty path component to your GOPATH? (The program works as expected for me on OSX13.3.0)

Comment: @DmitriGoldring I think you may be right . I have ``export GOPATH=/Users/me/go/``